# SDO Geometry. Calculate shortest distance

Tags: oracle, geometry, coordinates, distance

I have coordinates of place stored as struct object and coordinates of buildings stored as Doubles.

```
select geo.id, geo.object_id, geo.object_type, geo.date_created, t.x as longitude, t.y as latitude from geolocation geo, table(sdo_util.getvertices(geo.location)) t; --I can fetch places coordinates.
```

select longitude, latitude from building -- Fetch buildings locations.

I have to find in which building this place is located (the shortest distance to the near building).
i.e.

```
Place: longitude = 41.1111111, langitude = 42.2222222
Building 1: longitude = 41.1111112, langitude = 42.42.2222223
Building 2: longitude = 50.1111111, langitude = 50.2222222
Building 3: longitude = 60.1111111, langitude = 60.2222222
```

(I exaggerated values deliberately)

The result should be: building 1 (this is the near building).

How can I use SDO_GEOM.SDO_DISTANCE ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. I know nothing about SDO_GEOM. But I can show a few maths, if that helps:

Define a vector centre-of-Earth to point1. Define another vector with the centre-of-Earth and another point. The dot product of both vectors gives you the cosine of the angle between these two vectors.

The point with maximum dot-product is the closest point to point1.

For dot product with spherical coordinates see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243142/what-is-the-general-formula-for-calculating-dot-and-cross-products-in-spherical) post.

You can take the aproximation that all vectors have the same `r`. Because you are interested in maximum values (not real distances) you can use `r1 = r2 = 1`

Also, in that post `φ = 90 - latitude`. Remember sin(a) = cos(90-a).

Doing both corrections the final formula you need is

```
d = cosφ1 cosφ2 cos(θ1−θ2) + sinφ1 sinφ2
```

with `φ` = latitude   and `θ` = longitude

Comment: Do you mean *maximum* dot-product? must be closest to the product of the magnitudes

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Yes. Thanks for pointing that bug. I've fixed it now.